# Не возможно определеть метод из класса

Tags: php, ооп

У меня небольшая метод, где я подключаю ЧПУ ссылки в каждый модуль. Этот метод подключает все ЧПУ ссылки в главную страницу сайта, на единую точку входа. Вот он:

```
<?php
 /*
 * Получаю роутеры из модулей.
 */
public function getRoutes()
{
    if($this->counting() > 0)
    {
        $this->list = $this->db->query("SELECT `module`, `ru_name`, `version`, `author_e-mail` FROM `modules` ORDER BY `module`");

        while ($module = $this->list->fetch())
        {
            if(file_exists(H. $this->module_directory.'/'.$module['module'].'/system/routes.php'))
            {
                require H. $this->module_directory.'/'.$module['module'].'/system/routes.php';
            }
            else 
            {
                echo 'Роутеры в модуле "'.$module['ru_name'].'" не найдены. Обратитесь за технической поддержкой к разработчику даного модуля - '.$module['author_e-mail'];
                //$this->db->close();
            }
        }
    }
    r($this->list);
}
?>
```

А вызываю я его так:

```
    <?php
    /*
     * Инициализация класса Module
     */
$module = new Module(Vars::get('settings/MYSQL'));

/*
 * Подключение
 */
$router = new AltoRouter();

$module->getRoutes();

// match current request
$match = $router->match();

if($match['target']) {
    require H. $match['target'];
}
else
{
    Redirect::go();
}
```

На выходе получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function map() on null in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\cms\module\user\system\routes.php on line 4

Файл routes.php:

```
<?php

//Пользователь
$router->map('GET','/profile/[i:id]', '/module/user/profile.php', 'profile');
$router->map('GET|POST','/profile/edit', '/module/user/edit.php', 'profile_edit');
```

По идее, этот файл должен подключатся в корень сайта, и класс AltoRouter должен подхватывать этот код... но этого не происходит.

Comment: А где определяется $router в routes.php? Он об этом и выкидывает ошибку - $router там null. Вам наверняка надо сделать include или require_once на routes.php из основного файла.

Comment: На каждый модуль создавать экземпляр класса роутер? Он же вроде должен встраиваться в главный файл, где $router уже определен

Comment: В Yii1 (и в Yii2, вероятно) каждый модуль имеет в себе механизм роутинга;
можно иметь и коренной - но это будет, как вы и сказали, в одном файле. Кому как удобнее.